# собрать данные из DIV в JSON

Tags: html, jquery, json

Есть динамически сформированная корзина заказа (условно):

```
<div class="bin" id="bin">
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- первый товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">...</div>
  <div class="count">...</div>
  <div class="total_price">...</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- второй товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">наименование_товар_1</div>
  <div class="count">количество_товар_1</div>
  <div class="total_price">цена_товар_1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- третий товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">...</div>
  <div class="count">...</div>
  <div class="total_price">...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Количество, тип и цена этих товаров заранее неизвестны. 
Подскажите, как собрать все это в JSON для последующей передачи на email.

Предположение: 
подсчитать количество дочерних элементов .bin_item: $(".bin_item").length, а затем обращаться к каждому .bin_item[] и собирать информацию о значениях в  по заранее известным class'ам тупо пихать в JSON-строку:

```
{товар:наименование_товар_1, количество:количество_товар_1, цена:цена_товар_1 },
{товар:наименование_товар_2, количество:количество_товар_2, цена:цена_товар_2 }, 
{товар:наименование_товар_3, количество:количество_товар_3, цена:цена_товар_3 }
```

Вопрос: как получить данные из .bin_item[1], а затем .bin_item[1].type ?

Или, очень может быть, есть другой способ решения этой задачи - пока я для себя определил только такой ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто пробегаемся в цикле по всем `bin_item`. Так же не называйте классы с точкой иначе не сможете потом использовать в селекторе.

```js
var data = [];

$('.bin_item').each(function() {
  $el = $(this);
  data.push({
    type: $el.find('.type').text(),
    count: $el.find('.count').text(),
    total_price: $el.find('.total_price').text(),
  })
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bin" id="bin">
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- первый товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">...</div>
  <div class="count">...</div>
  <div class="total_price">...</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- второй товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">наименование_товар_1</div>
  <div class="count">количество_товар_1</div>
  <div class="total_price">цена_товар_1</div>
 </div>
 <div class="bin_item"> <!-- третий товар заказа -->
  <div class="type">...</div>
  <div class="count">...</div>
  <div class="total_price">...</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А вот с точкой я просто пропустил (читай протупил) - долго возился с JQ и на автомате в имени классов ее проставил.

Comment: Исправил - мало-ли кому понадобится ...

Comment: Не кажется ли вам небезопасным собирать информацию из элементов на странице? Ведь через дебаггер туда можно записать что угодно. Есть риск инъекции

Comment: Согласен! Но на настоящем этапе пока это не принципиально, поскольку это не реальный "магазин", а лишь его прототип, создаваемый больше в целях самообучения. И сразу параллельный вопрос - как в таком случае избежать возможности инъекции, если "товары" могут добавляться/удаляться до выполнения этого кода?